# asp.net mvc 3 - remove time from date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, view

I am having a model in with a DateTime property:

```
    public DateTime? DateNaissance { get; set; }
```

and a View with a @Html.TextBoxFor for the property

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateNaissance)
```

All I want is to get the date typed, however, when I type in 01/06/2012 as date I am having the "01/06/2012 00:00:00" in the controller

All I want is to get the date, why the time is added ?, how to automatically remove it ?

I tried out without success:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `ApplyFormatInEditMode` property of the `DisplayFormat`attribute to true and then use `EditorFor` instead of `TextboxFor`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]    

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateNaissance)
```

#### Update

If you need to do this for every date, you can also put a file called DateTime.cshtml in \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ with this in it:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty))
```

This will use "dd/MM/yyyy" for DateTimes when you use `EditorFor`.

Comment: Hi, It doesn' t work for me, still having {01/06/2012 00:00:00} format as return controller post :(

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried the second option with the EditorTemplate?

Comment: Hi, I didn' t try the EditorTemplate as I want on some of the dates use the date and, but not this one. And the method apply to all the dates isn' t.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I thought you were talking about how the date was displayed in the view, but you are talking about how an entered date is returned to the controller, right? Well, the name of the object says it: DateTime. It is a Date _and_ a Time. You can't have a date without a time when using a DateTime object.

Comment: Yes indeed, all I want is to get the entered date returned to the controller, that is what I am thinking of, that' s mean that I have to do some processing to extract the date every time ?

Comment: You can't extract the time of a DateTime object. If you just enter a date and no time, the time will be set to 00:00:00. That's as close you can get to a DateTime with just a date.

Comment: How can I do this on a website that relies on globalisation to automatically pick up the clients culture. I still don't want the time to display (nobody does!) but I can't supply a static format as the separators and the order of date components are dependent on culture.

Comment: ^^ this can be done with the DataType attribute `[DataType( DataType.Date )]` which also removes the time component from the display FYI

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to say that you will get **always** the time since your object is of DateTime type. If you want to use only the Date, on your controller you need to get only the Date part with DateNaissance.Date, but again the object will always have the time part on it