# Excluding time from TextBoxFor when ViewModel setup as DataType of Date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to properly display a (nullable) Date-type-only field. For this field, my Model and ViewModel classes are defined as....

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:M/dd/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]       
public DateTime? PeriodEnd { get; set; }
```

In my details view (based on model), it's showing the date properly (excluding the time element):

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PeriodEnd)
```

Problem: In my edit view (based on ViewModel), it's showing the time also, which I'm trying to exclude. Here's how it's defined.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodEnd, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

I also tried....

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodEnd.Value().ToShortDateString(), 
    new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

... but that produced an error.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179027/asp-net-mvc-3-remove-time-from-date

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you're not utilizing the data annotation. Something like `DataType.Date` doesn't do anything on its own. Using editor templates (`Html.EditorFor`), it can be utilized to provide an `date` type input, but if you use `Html.TextBoxFor`, it's basically ignored.

You can fix that by either 1) using `Html.EditorFor` instead or 2) explicitly setting the type: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PeriodEnd, new { type = "date", @class = "datepicker" })`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt. I tried both suggestions, but then the textbox showed the text/mask of "mm/dd/yyyy" (literally).

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PeriodEnd, "{0:M/d/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Thanks to all for your feedback!